# Angular 4 Two-Way Data Binding breaks with EventListener

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, data-binding, dom-events

I have the problem, that my data bindings break if I push the Ionic Page by an event listener event.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
document.addEventListener('admob.rewardvideo.events.REWARD', () => {
  this.goToScriptedGame();
});
```

The user has to watch the ad video, before he can access the page.

Sadly all two-way bindings like `{{title}}` don't change anymore, they only show the init value.

I discovered, that if a press the "devices" back button (which is disabled at a certain point) the values are shown correctly.

The variables themselves are all correct and everything is working fine but it's just the broken binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger change detection manually, when you want to bind to events via `document.addEventListener`, otherwise angular does not know about it.

You are probably looking for `ApplicationRef#tick()`, that will trigger full component tree change detection.

```
import { ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private appRef: ApplicationRef) {}

ionViewDidLoad() {
  document.addEventListener('admob.rewardvideo.events.REWARD', () => {
    this.goToScriptedGame();
    this.appRef.tick();
  });
}
```

See this question for more information and other possibilities: [Triggering Angular2 change detection manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually)

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(public zone: NgZone) {}

ionViewDidLoad() {
document.addEventListener('admob.rewardvideo.events.REWARD', () => {
  this.zone.run(() =>
    this.navCtrl.push("ScriptedPage")
  );
});
```

NgZone made it perfectly for me! Thanks for you link to this post, where I found out about it.

Your provided solution didn't work well but the idea was correct.